# Storing an array that exceeds 4096 bytes for a week

Tags: javascript, arrays, session, cookies, text-files

I need to store an array that exceeds 4096 bytes for a week, and I can't use cookies because cookies have a maximum limit of 4096 bytes per domain. I can't use sessions either, even though they have a maximum limit of 5MB because sessions expire after the browser is closed.

I thought about writing it directly to a text file on my computer, but I read that you can't do that, and the best you can do is create a download link every time to click on to download the text file to your computer.

I need a way to store an array that exceeds 4096 bytes for a week, and I need a way to store it automatically, without having to click any download links every time it needs to be updated. Any way this can possibly be done?

Comment: @Emma You can but it has to be a download link, and I need it to be automatic, without clicking every time when it updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider usage of LocalStorage of browser. In Chrome, Firefox and IE it can contain up to 10MB. Hope that helps.

Comment: Is it 10MB per domain, or just 10MB period?

Comment: I think per domain, so in total you can store up to 10 MB for your app